# lapply with second iteration in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have two lists, one containing 2 data.frames and the other containing 2 vectors.

I need to set the column names in the data.frames to the vectors in the other list, can't seem to wrap my head around how to do that with lapply.

reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    Z = sample(LETTERS,10),
    X = sample(1:10),
    Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
dataframes <- list(df1, df2)
columns <- list(c("numbers", "boolean"),c("letters", "numbers", "boolean"))
```

Data frames have different number of columns and column names are very different in my original data. What i've been trying to do is to map the columns list as colnames for the data frames using lapply but I need to iterate through `columns` and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map(setNames, dataframes, columns)

# [[1]]
#    numbers boolean
# 1        3     yes
# 2        4     yes
# 3        5      no
# 4        7     yes
# 5        2      no
# 6        8     yes
# 7        9      no
# 8        6      no
# 9       10     yes
# 10       1      no
# 
# [[2]]
#    letters numbers boolean
# 1        Y       5      no
# 2        F       6      no
# 3        P       4      no
# 4        C       2      no
# 5        Z      10      no
# 6        I       8      no
# 7        A       9     yes
# 8        H       1     yes
# 9        X       7      no
# 10       V       3      no
```

Comment: Thank you, I just needed to replace lapply with Map! Will accept in 10 min when it lets me

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `map2`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(dataframes, columns, set_names)
#[[1]]
#   numbers boolean
#1        3     yes
#2        4     yes
#3        5      no
#4        7     yes
#5        2      no
#6        8     yes
#7        9      no
#8        6      no
#9       10     yes
#10       1      no

#[[2]]
#   letters numbers boolean
#1        Y       5      no
#2        F       6      no
#3        P       4      no
#4        C       2      no
#5        Z      10      no
#6        I       8      no
#7        A       9     yes
#8        H       1     yes
#9        X       7      no
#10       V       3      no
```

Comment: Is this faster than map ?

Comment: @aginensky Did you meant `Map`?

Comment: @aginensky  I would say the tidyverse functions are created for consistency, easiness to understand.  In the process, it can also speed up.  If you want to check the speeds of both, then try with `microbenchmark` on a bigger dataset